# mpandroidchart line chart x axis labels overlap issue occuring

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

Actually We are trying to render the line chart with depending on the data that we have, the data is getting render on two way, weekly and daily basis. The line chart consists of x-axis which displays dates but the dates that are getting the list down in x-axis are overlapping each other. 
Please check this image to take a look : https://pasteboard.co/Iya3jWL.jpg 
Following is currently code that I have applied for line chart in order to tweak the line chart look.

```
final ArrayList<ILineDataSet> linedataSets = new ArrayList<>();

            LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(ptsModel.yVals7, "Male");
            set1.setFillAlpha(110);
            set1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1C8AF9"));
            set1.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor("#1C8AF9"));
            set1.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#9C1C8AF9"));
            set1.setLineWidth(2f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(9f);
            set1.setDrawFilled(true);
            set1.setDrawValues(false);
            set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

            LineDataSet set2 = new LineDataSet(ptsModel.yVals8, "Female");
            set2.setFillAlpha(110);
            set2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F92F81"));
            set2.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor("#F92F81"));
            set2.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#B0F92F81"));
            set2.setLineWidth(2f);
            set2.setCircleRadius(3f);
            set2.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set2.setValueTextSize(9f);
            set2.setDrawFilled(true);
            set2.setDrawValues(false);
            set2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

            linedataSets.add(set1);
            linedataSets.add(set2);

            LineData linedata = new LineData(linedataSets);
            gendertrendschart.setData(linedata);
            gendertrendschart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gendertrendschart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true);

            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
            gendertrendschart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(true);
            gendertrendschart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true);
            gendertrendschart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
            /*int valOffset = (int) (set1.getCircleRadius() * 1.75f);
            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setXOffset(valOffset);*/
            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            gendertrendschart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(ptsModel.xVals.size(), true);
            gendertrendschart.setMaxHighlightDistance(20);
            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
            gendertrendschart.getAxisLeft().setGranularityEnabled(true);
            gendertrendschart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());

            gendertrendschart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);
            gendertrendschart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

            gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(true);
gendertrendschart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(ptsModel.xVals));
```

I try finding solution in their GitHub repository but unable to find proper solution, it would be nice if you could help us.

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to your code:

```
barChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
barChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1.0f);
lineChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(3);  // give any number here for visible labels
```

You can get labels for other entries upon zooming

Comment: that is not what he asked!

Answer (score 0):

> You can do one thing to get your desired output, that is you have to make x-axis label with two-line. So, it will not overlaps labels.
>   For that just put "\n" in middle of you each label in the x-axis value list.

In your case, I think you display Date in your x-axis. you just put "\n" at the middle of your SimpleDateFortmater.

Like : `"dd/MM\nyyyy"`